How do I disable (or correctly enable) Cassandra table compression with JanusGraph?
I'm connecting to a cassandra cluster from janusgraph all running in kubernetes. Cassandra is version 5.0.0-jammy and Janusgraph is version 1.0.0 (image container info here)
The two Cassandra nodes seem ok, but the Janusgraph container throws the error below when the container starts. I can not find any references to this compression.class property within cassandra, janusgraph, or gremlin server docs. The closest reference I see is to the cassandra tables.
I've tried the permutations of the table compression related janusgraph settings for janusgraph.properties but none of them have had an impact:
V1
storage.cql.compression=false
storage.cql.compression-type=

V2
root.storage.cql.compression=false
root.storage.cql.compression-type=

V3
storage.cql.compression=true
storage.cql.compression-type=LZ4Compressor

V4
root.storage.cql.compression=true
root.storage.cql.compression-type=LZ4Compressor

Error Being Throw

Caused by:
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.InvalidConfigurationInQueryException:
Missing sub-option 'class' for the 'compression' option.  at
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.InvalidConfigurationInQueryException.copy(InvalidConfigurationInQueryException.java:52)
~[java-driver-core-4.17.0.jar:?]  at
com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.concurrent.CompletableFutures.getUninterruptibly(CompletableFutures.java:149)
~[java-driver-core-4.17.0.jar:?]  at
com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestSyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestSyncProcessor.java:53)
~[java-driver-core-4.17.0.jar:?]  at
com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestSyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestSyncProcessor.java:30)
~[java-driver-core-4.17.0.jar:?]  at
com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:230)
~[java-driver-core-4.17.0.jar:?]  at
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.SyncCqlSession.execute(SyncCqlSession.java:54)
~[java-driver-core-4.17.0.jar:?]  at
org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLKeyColumnValueStore.initializeTable(CQLKeyColumnValueStore.java:311)
~[janusgraph-cql-1.0.0.jar:?]     at
org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLKeyColumnValueStore.(CQLKeyColumnValueStore.java:189)
~[janusgraph-cql-1.0.0.jar:?]     at
org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLStoreManager.lambda$openDatabase$7(CQLStoreManager.java:308)
~[janusgraph-cql-1.0.0.jar:?]     at
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source)
~[?:?]    at
org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLStoreManager.openDatabase(CQLStoreManager.java:308)
~[janusgraph-cql-1.0.0.jar:?]

janusgraph-gremlin-server.yaml
host: 0.0.0.0
port: 8182
evaluationTimeout: 30000
channelizer: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.WebSocketChannelizer
graphManager: org.janusgraph.graphdb.management.JanusGraphManager
graphs: {
  ConfigurationManagementGraph: /etc/opt/janusgraph/janusgraph.properties
}   
scriptEngines: {
  gremlin-groovy: {
    plugins: { org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.plugin.JanusGraphGremlinPlugin: {}, 
               org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.jsr223.GremlinServerGremlinPlugin: {}, 
               org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.jsr223.TinkerGraphGremlinPlugin: {}, 
               org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.ImportGremlinPlugin: {classImports: [java.lang.Math], methodImports: [java.lang.Math#*]},
               org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.ScriptFileGremlinPlugin: {files: []}}}}
serializers:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.util.ser.GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1,
      config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.util.ser.GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1,
      config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.util.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3,
      config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
processors:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.session.SessionOpProcessor, config: { sessionTimeout: 28800000 }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.traversal.TraversalOpProcessor, config: { cacheExpirationTime: 600000, cacheMaxSize: 1000 }}

janusgraph.properties file
gremlin.graph=org.janusgraph.core.ConfiguredGraphFactory
graph.graphname=ConfigurationManagementGraph

storage.backend=cql
storage.hostname=cassandra
storage.cql.local-datacenter=DC1

cache.db-cache=true
cache.db-cache-clean-wait=20
cache.db-cache-time=191000
cache.db-cache-size=0.5

